# AndEngine and AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, andengine

I downloaded AndEngine, imported it to AndroidStudio and added it as a dependence to my AndroidStudio project. When it comes to compiling, though, the linker fails when finding GLES2. Specifically, I get these errors:

```
Warning:(9, 63) warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
Warning:(13, 36) warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
Error:(9) undefined reference to `glVertexAttribPointer' 
Error:(13) undefined reference to `glDrawElements'
```

I installed the libgles2-mesa package (Ubuntu 12.04) and created a symbolic in `/usr/lib/libGLESv2.so.2` to the library. Still, the linker seems not to find the library.

Comment: Come up with any solution? I'm running across the same thing.

Comment: I'm sorry I could not fix it and I'm afraid I'm not longer working on that computer. Hope you fix it :)